# Succinctly express Jacobian of a simple vector-valued function as a matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, jacobian

For any $U \in \mathbb R^{m \times d}$ and $v \in \mathbb R^m$, let $\theta = \mathrm{cat}(\mathrm{vec}(U),\mathrm{vec}(v)) \in \mathbb R^{N}$ be the concatenation of the vectorization of $U$ and $v$, where $N:=m(d+1)$. Note that $(U,v)$ and $\theta$ are equivalent representations of the same object. Consider the function $T:\mathbb R^N \to \mathbb R^d$ defined by $T(\theta) := U^\top v \in \mathbb R^d$.

**Question 1.** How to succinctly write the Jacobian $\nabla T (\theta)$ as an $N \times d$ matrix in terms of $U$ and $v$ ?

I think this should be possible via some clever usage of Kronecker products, Hadamard products, block matrices, etc., but my matrix calculus skills are a bit rusty.

**Question 2.** Is it true that $\nabla T(\theta)$ has full rank $d$ for almost all $\theta$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\bs{\boldsymbol}
\def\t{\theta}\def\e{\varepsilon}\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{c|c}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$Define the zero vector $z\in\bbR{d},\;$ the identity matrix $I\in\bbR{d\times d},\;$ the augmented matrix and its Gramian
$$\eqalign{
A &= {\bs[}\,U\;v\,{\bs]}
   = {\bs[}\,u_1\;u_2\:\cdots\ u_d\:\,v\,{\bs]}, \qquad
A^TA &= \m{U^TU&U^Tv\\\hline v^TU&v^Tv} \\
}$$
where the $(1,2)$ block of the latter is the required vector function.

Now define block matrix analogs of the standard cartesian basis vectors
$$\eqalign{
E_1 = \m{I \\ z^T} \qquad E_2 = \m{z \\ \o} \;\equiv\; e  \\
}$$
which allow us to extract the desired $(1,2)$ partition as
$$\eqalign{
T \;=\; U^Tv \;=\; E_1^T\LR{A^TA}E_2 \\
}$$
Calculate the differential of the $T$ function
$$\eqalign{
dT &= E_1^T\LR{A^TdA+dA^TA}e \\&= E_1^TA^TdA\,e + E_1^TdA^TAe \\
}$$
Then [vectorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) it and isolate the gradient wrt $\t$
$$\eqalign{
 \t &= \vc{A} \\
d\t &= \vc{dA} \\
 dT &= \LR{e\otimes AE_1}^T d\t + \LR{E_1\otimes Ae}^T d\t \\
\grad{T}{\t} &= \LR{e\otimes AE_1 \;+\; E_1\otimes Ae}^T \\
}$$
You might want to transpose this result, depending on your preferred [layout convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions).